# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, ld, 16-bit

Recently, I was trying to compile a C program into 16-bit with this command:

```
gcc -m16 main.c
```

all was going well until I saw these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong and how do I fix these errors?